# Cakephp 3 creating multiple entity's rows from form

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to save multiple rows of a same entity but I'm failing to create the form.

So.. This is my controller: CuotasController

```
    $cuotas = array();
    $date = Time::create($inicioPago->year, $inicioPago->month, $inicioPago->day);
    $meses = 0;

    while ($date < $finPago) {
        $cuota = $this->Cuotas->newEntity();
        $cuota->vencimiento = $date;
        array_push($cuotas, $cuota);
        $date = Time::create($date->year, $date->month + 1, $date->day);
        $meses = $meses + 1;
    }
```

Basically, in this code I generate an array of Cuotas (my entity) and the populate dynamically that array.

So here's the form:

```
                    <?= $this->Form->create($cuotas) ?>
                    <?php foreach ($cuotas as $cuota): ?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input text required">
                                        <?php  echo $this->Form->input('vencimiento',  ['required' => true, ['class' => 'form-control'] ] ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input text required">
                                        <?php  echo $this->Form->input('monto_pesos',  ['required' => true, 'class' => 'form-control' ] ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input text required">
                                        <?php  echo $this->Form->input('monto_dolares',  ['required' => true, 'class' => 'form-control' ] ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Volver'), ['action' => 'index'] , array('class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'style' => 'margin-top:1em') ) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->button(__('Guardar'), ['class'=>'btn btn-success', 'style' => 'margin-top:1em']) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Finally, in the controller, this is how I try to patch the entities:

```
$entities = $this->Cuotas->newEntities($this->request->data);
```

Do you know where I am messing it all up?

Thanks!

Comment: after submitting form data is identified using field name, in you form all field names are same, please check that, then you can use different names for different fields or use array type name,
then after submit you have to format those data in to a set of arrays of a array $data=[ [], [], [], []]
containing yours entities data separately,
then you can use 
$entities = $this->Cuotas->newEntities($data);
$this->Cuotas->saveMany($entities );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are overwriting the form on each iteration.

Inspect the html generated code, if this looks like:

```
<input name="abc[property_name]" />
```

Check if in the next row it looks equal.

You sould have something like this:

```
<input name="abc[0][one_prop]" />
<input name="abc[0][other_prop]" />

<input name="abc[1][one_prop]" />
<input name="abc[1][other_prop]" />
```

Is much better if you use the id of the entity to identify when is submitted.